# Rails Route parameters in AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am trying to build an AngularJS/Rails multi-page app WITHOUT the use of ngView- basically, I want to use Angular's data-binding and other features in my rails app while still having the views determined by my Rails routes. So far, it is working alright, but my main problem has been accessing my rails routes parameters from within my Angular framework. Is there a way to access the URL/parameters in an Angular-friendly way? I don't want to resort to slicing up window.location.

For example, lets say I'm in localhost:3000/articles/1, with my view would corresponding to app/views/article/show.html.erb

```
<div class='articleContainer' ng-controller='ArticleController'>
  <div class='articleTitle' ng-bind='article.title'></div>
  <div class='articleBody' ng-bind='article.body'></div>
</div>
```

This is what my ArticleController would look like in a traditional Angular setup.

```
var ArticlesControllers = angular.module('ArticlesControllers', ['ngSanitize']);

ArticlesControllers.controller('ArticleController', ['$scope', '$routeParams',"$http","$browser","$sniffer","$rootElement", "$location",
  function($scope, $location, $http, $resource){
    $http.get('/articles/'+$routeParams.articleId+'.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.article = data["article"];
      $scope.comments = data["comments"];
    });

  }
]);
```

Unfortunately, $routeParams does not seem to work if I am not using an ngView. Is there a clean way to recreate $routeParams.articleId without resorting to window.location? Thank you kindly.

Comment: I'm just getting into Angular, so not completely sure. But couldn't you add a non-visible div with an ng-binding to article.id and then reference its content when you need it?

Comment: Also, you might find the Less JS Routes gem (by Steven Bristol from LessEverything) useful. It will allow you to replace '/articles/'+$routeParams.articleId+'.json' with a function call built from your actual routes. Very useful for accessing your Rails routes in js.

Comment: I just don't know how I could pull the article id in order to bind to it. Same problem with the Less JS routes. Looks like it would definitely come in handy, I just don't know I could pull down the article id to pass it in.

Answer (score 0):

Embed the article id in a data element on the articleContainer div, like so:

```
<div class='articleContainer' ng-controller='ArticleController' id='articleContainer' data-article-id=<% =@article.id.to_s %> >
  <div class='articleTitle' ng-bind='article.title'></div>
  <div class='articleBody' ng-bind='article.body'></div>
</div>
```

I added an id to the div for easy reference via javascript.

Then, in your javascript retrieve that data element when you need it:

(assumes jQuery)

```
var articleId = $('#articleContainer').data('article-id');
```

Comment: I will likely do something similar to this. Thanks.

Comment: You seem unsure. Do you want to discuss it further?

Comment: This was my fallback plan, honestly. I was really hoping to avoid resorting to ERB, but not the end of the world if I have to use it. Thanks though.

Comment: @Pavlov's_Dawg Did you find cleaner alternative? I am also encountering the same issue, but not sure what the cleanest solution is. Thinking of using https://github.com/gazay/gon...