# Rails 4 routes + AngularJS: How would I grab the products/:id parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm trying to use pure Rails routes with AngularJS controllers. How would I grab the product id (30) of `/products/30` in my Angular controller if the route is being generated by Rails?

```
app.controller('ProductCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  // grab id param
  // and then do something like Product.query({id: id_param});
}]);
```

I have the same issue as this guy: [Rails Route parameters in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048570/rails-route-parameters-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to do something like embedding the ID in a attribute (as discussed in [Rails Route parameters in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048570/rails-route-parameters-in-angularjs)) I would probably end up using $location.path() to grab the path and splitting it up as needed.